# How do i compare an attribute from a class with a string?

Tags: java, arrays, attributes, equals

How do i properly write the third line? I have an array zivali that contains name, surname and other attributes. I need to compare only the Name (ime) attribute from each zivali array element. Is it with equals, = or == and how can i properly write it? Thank you all, looking forward to your answer

```
public boolean zivalObstaja(String ime) {
    for(int i=0; i<zivali.length; i++) {
        **if(zivali[i].ime==(ime))** {
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways to compare string in java

1. By `equals()` method

   The String `equals()` method compares the original content of the string.
2. By `==` operator

   The `==` operator compares references not values.
3. By `compareTo()` method

   The String `compareTo()` method compares values and returns an integer value that describes
   if first string is less than, equal to or greater than second string.

Since you want to compare the original content of the string. You have to use first one.

```
public boolean zivalObstaja(String ime) {
    for(int i=0; i<zivali.length; i++) {
       if (zivali[i].ime.equals(ime)) {
          return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, you were very helpful! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `String.equals`:

```
if (zivali[i].ime.equals(ime)) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, you were very helpful! :)